# Строковое объединения результата выборки двух полей

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть запрос вида:
    SELECT idArticle AS ID FROM articles

Можно ли сделать что-то наподобие:
SELECT ***(idArticle, NameAticle)*** AS ID FROM articles

Чтобы в **ID** поместился результат в виде строки c разделителем: **idArticle#NameAticle**?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('#', idArticle, NameAticle) AS ID FROM articles
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вспомнил - давным - давно в книге читал о CONCAT